# Try Catch and then continue

Tags: asp.net, exception, try-catch

I have some code which goes in a for loop and then sends emails off using another function.

When there is an error it does not continue to send emails after the email that had the issue.

I would like the error to be caught and the system to continue sending the rest of the emails. Please see code below.

```
public static SendEmailResult setEmailAndSend(DataRow[] rows)
{
    try
    {
        SendEmailResult results = new SendEmailResult();

        foreach (DataRow row in rows)
        {
            try
            {
                //Set Values here
                string strFN = row["FirstName"].ToString();
                string strLN = row["LastName"].ToString();
                string strEmail = row["Email"].ToString();
                //some more here


                 Sent = EmailFunctions.SendEmail(strEmail, strFromAddress, strFromName, strSubject, strFN + " " + strLN, strBody, strSignOffEmbeddedImagePath, strSignOffEmbeddedImageName, strCCReminderEmail);
             }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                //do stuff

                continue;
            }
       }
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {
        //do something
    }
}


public static bool SendEmail(String strToAddress, String strFromAddress, String strFromName, String strSubject, String strRecipientName, String strBody, String strEmbeddedImagePath, String strEmbeddedImageName, String strCCReminderEmail)
{
    try
    {
        //SMTPClient settings in webconfig
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.EnableSsl = true;

        using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage(
            new MailAddress(strFromAddress, strFromName),
            new MailAddress(strToAddress, strRecipientName)))
        {
            message.IsBodyHtml = true;
            message.Subject = strSubject;
            message.Body = strBody;

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strCCReminderEmail))
                message.CC.Add(strCCReminderEmail);

            client.Send(message);

            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;

    }
}
```

Comment: Why am i being voted down.

Answer (score 1):

You need to move the `try catch` block inside the foreach statement:

```
foreach (DataRow row in rows)
     {
                    try
                    {
                        //Set Values here
                        string strFN = row["FirstName"].ToString();
                        string strLN = row["LastName"].ToString();
                        string strEmail = row["Email"].ToString();
                        //some more here


                        Sent = EmailFunctions.SendEmail(strEmail, strFromAddress, strFromName, strSubject, strFN + " " + strLN, strBody, strSignOffEmbeddedImagePath, strSignOffEmbeddedImageName, strCCReminderEmail);
                    }
                    catch (Exception exc)
                    {
                        //Log exception!!
                        continue;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add that in there, i have added it into my example but was still having issues.

Comment: What are the issues are you getting?, please provide more details here.

Answer (score 0):

You should `try catch` only those areas you expect might go wrong even in normal usage like the internet, IO, stream and so on.

In your case, `SendEmail(...)` it is, so

```
try
{
    Sent = EmailFunctions.SendEmail(...);
} 
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // Capture mail send exception
}
```

Or just

```
public static bool SendEmail(...)
{
    try
    {
        ...
        using (MailMessage message = new MailMessage(...))
        {
           ...

            return true;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {        
        // Some function to record which mail didn't send
        return false;
    }
}
```

Since `throw` doesn't seem necessary here.

You can keep the `try catch` outside `foreach` if you want to capture DB access problem too(but remove the `continue`, it's meaningless outside the loop).

Comment: What exactly the issues are? Any exception message?